# Javascript function that is equivalent for PHP function

Tags: php, javascript

I have the follwing code in PHP:

```
if(is_numeric($first_name[0]) === true){
   //Do something
}
```

How would I be able to do the same check using JavaScript?  I also would like to get a PHP script to check if there is a number in $first_name at all, as I don't want the user to add a number in their first or last names please?

Comment: Do you want to check if the value is a number type (e.g. `3`), or a string that contains numbers (e.g. `"john3"`), or a string or number that is a "valid" number (e.g. `2.3` or `"2.3"`)?

Answer (score 1):

[Use regular expressions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```
if (/-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/.test(yourInput)) {
   // Do something
}
```

Of course, this will only work on strings.  For a different method, see a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric):

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

To only check if the input contains a number (0-9) at all, regex works again:

```
if (/[0-9]+/.test(yourInput)) {
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: That doesn't check "if there is a number in $first_name at all", it checks if it's only digits.

Comment: He wants a javascript alternative to `is_numeric`, which the docs say 
"Finds whether the given variable is numeric. Numeric strings consist of optional sign, any number of digits, optional decimal part and optional exponential part."

Comment: The first does not the same thing as PHP's `is_numeric` and your edit is just a [copy pasta of @Lochemage's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18115091/508666)

Comment: I dug up code I used for integer validation a while back that should actually meet the criteria.  And I did link to that question for a reason.  Edit - I see what you're saying.  Apparently we found the same link.

Comment: @MattBryant—it's not clear to me what the OP wants. :-/

Answer (score 1):

in js to check if the number variable is a number:

```
isFinite(number) && !isNaN(parseFloat(number))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric):

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable in question is `$first_name`

```
if( $first_name && !isNaN($first_name[0])) {

    // do something
}
```

Comment: There is a `$` in your first name lol

Comment: Ah the edit looks fine now :)

Comment: @woofmeow what's wrong with a `$`?

Comment: Well he didn't mention that the variable was `$first_name` in the beginning so it looked like a bad mixture of javascript and php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether *$first_name* contains any digits, then:

```
if (/\d/.test($first_name)) {
    // $first_name contains at least one digit
}
```